# Load rich text into innerHTML loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 divs: main div and secondary, which is an innerHTML page loaded upon clicking a link in the main div. Within the secondary div is a comment area inserted through python Django. To that comment area I am attempting to apply a rich text jquery plugin. I know that when using ajax, the script within the innerHTML page is stripped and only the content is loaded. I tried referencing the plugin in the main div, but it fires before the ajax page is loaded and thus the rich text still isn't applied. Is there a way to fire the plugin after loading the page? Or what is the best way to approach this problem? Would I be able to use onreadystatechange?

Main page:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
                <!-- bunch of content here -->
            </div>
    <div class="main">
                <!-- loads another HTML page -->
            </div>
```

Secondary page form field (on a separate HTML page) to which I am attempting to apply the rich text:

```
<p>{{ form.as_p }}</p>
```

Javascript load function:

```
var url;
$('.linkQuestion').on('click', 'a', function(ev) {
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.answers').load(url, function(){
        $.getScript('https://s3.amazonaws.com/javascript/richTextEditor.js', function() {
            bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() }); 
        });

    }); 
return false;
});
```

To call the plugin:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/richTextEditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
 </script>
```

I know there have been many similar questions already asked and I looked through all of them but I still can't get it to work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback and apply the plugin after the ajax request has finished.

```
$('.secondary').load(url, function(){
    // call your plugin here on the content. 
});
```

Comment: aziz I tried that, referencing the script on both the main page and on the secondary page. Seems to still not work

Comment: asovgir. How do you call the plugin on your page ? Can you post the code ? I have never used that plugin so i don't know how to call it. I will show you an example.

Comment: I don't think simply referencing it will work. You have to implicitly call the method on a jquery object.

Comment: Just added the plugin for how I would pull it normally. I referenced it like this: $('.secondary').load(url, function(){
   bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() }); 
  });

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url;
    $('.main a').on('click', function() {
        url = $(this).attr('href');

        $.get(url, function(result) {
            $('.secondary').html(result);
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

However you would need an element with class = "secondary" to put the content into

```
<p class="secondary"></p>
```

Comment: Scott the <p> with the form is a separate HTML page